# How to properly write a React Class Component that can receive props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know how to receive props in presentational components but currently I need to also use functions which have logic therefore I'm needed to change my component into a Class Component right now, I don't know why I'm not able to receive the props.

Here is a part of my component:

```
class MemberInfoSubPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
   this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  }
```

As you can see, I'm using ES6 & I'm trying to render rows from a map but for now I'm just trying to receive props. Is this code provided correct? I mean the usual syntax.

PS: For additional info, I'm receiving 'props' is not defined. So yea, I'm not receiving the props after changing my component. Previously I was able to receive the props.

**EDIT**:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ons from 'onsenui';
import * as Ons from 'react-onsenui';

class MemberInfoSubPage extends React.Component {
  //const result = FlightApi.getAllFlightList();
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
   // this.stateToEntry = this.stateToEntry.bind(this);
   this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  }

  renderRow(row,index) {
    const x = 40 + Math.round(5 * (Math.random() - 0.5)),
          y = 40 + Math.round(5 * (Math.random() - 0.5));

    const names = ['Max', 'Chloe', 'Bella', 'Oliver', 'Tiger', 'Lucy', 'Shadow', 'Angel'];
    const name = names[Math.floor(names.length * Math.random())];

    return (
      <Ons.ListItem key={index}>
        <div className='left'>
          <img src={`http://placekitten.com/g/${x}/${y}`} className='list__item__thumbnail' />
        </div>
        <div className='center'>
          {name}
        </div>
      </Ons.ListItem>
    );
  }

  render() {
      if (props['index'] == 0) {
        return (
          <div className="memberInfoSubPage">
            <div className="memberInfoSubPage-row1">

              <span>{props['data-user'].id}</span>

              <table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table">
                <tr>
                  <th style={{color: 'grey'}}>Rank</th>
                  <th style={{color: 'grey'}}>Country</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].rank}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].country}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div className="memberInfoSubPage2-Summary-Title">Placement Performance Summary</div>
              <table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table2">
                <tr>
                  <td>L</td>
                  <td>R</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].placementPerformanceSummary.L}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].placementPerformanceSummary.R}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
             <div>
              <div className="memberInfoSubPage2-Summary-Title">Today Detail</div>
              <table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table3">
                <tr>
                  <td>L</td>
                  <td>R</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].todayDetail.L}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].todayDetail.R}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div> <table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table3">
                <tr><th style={{color: 'grey'}}>Next Level Upgrade</th></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].nextLevelUpgrade}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>

            <Ons.Button style={{margin: '6px'}}>Instant Upgrade</Ons.Button>


            <div>
              <div className="memberInfoSubPage2-Summary-Title" style={{color: 'grey'}}>Conversion Share Platform Portfolio</div>
              <table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table3">
                <tr style={{color: 'grey'}}>
                  <th>Market($)</th>
                  <th>Unit</th>
                  <th>Tradable Unit</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].market}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].unit}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].tradableUnit}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
             <div><table border={1} className="memberInfoSubPage-Table3">
                <tr style={{color: 'grey'}}>
                  <th>Lock Units</th>
                  <th>Avg Price</th>
                  <th>Last Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].lockUnits}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].avgPrice}</td>
                  <td>{props['data-user'].lastPrice}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      else  if (props['index'] == 1) {
        return (
            <Ons.List
            dataSource={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            renderHeader={() => <Ons.ListHeader>Summary</Ons.ListHeader>}/>
              /*<div className="memberInfoSubPage2-Summary-Title">Summary</div>
              <table className="memberInfoSubPage2-Summary-Table">
                <tr><td>Credit</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.credit}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Register</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.register}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>CP(S)</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.cpS}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>CP(0)</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.cp0}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>AP</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.ap}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>BO Point</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.boPoint}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Listed Company Fund</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.listedCompanyFund}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Promo</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.promo}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>TT</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.tt}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Re-Entry Point</td><td>{props['data-user'].summary.reEntryPoint}</td></tr>
              </table>*/
        );
      }
      else {
        return (
          <p>Not receiving any index. No content can be shown.</p>
        );
      }
  }
};

MemberInfoSubPage.propTypes = {
  'data-pageName': PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  'defaultOption': PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  'error': PropTypes.string,
  'options': PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
};

export default MemberInfoSubPage;
```

Here is my code, I'm pretty sure I've missed something.
There is still a lot of unrefined code and the function `renderRow` & that `Onsen` list is copy pasted.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: When/where are you receiving the props is not defined message?

Comment: @Vijay Okay thanks, I'm receving 'props' is not defined so I thought my syntax was wrong. I guess I'll take a further look into my code. Would you like me to show my full component code so that you can help me fix it? Its most probably just some missing some bracket `{` or `(`

Comment: @sma I'm getting a red screen with that error stating its at the 2nd line of bundle.js. Its probably source code typo. I'll add my component code in the question in a couple of minutes.

Comment: You need to refer to props as `this.props` rather than just `props`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props` is on the component instance, so you'll need to refer to it as `this.props` rather than just `props` in your `render` function.